# Image displayed as white in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-image-crop

I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` to upload images from my device to the backend server. I am able to upload and save images to the server successfully. But If I sign out from my application and sign in back, the image filed is showing as white color instead of uploaded image.

Image has been saved to the backend with the path as `file:///data/user/0/com.project/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20201209_230314.jpg`.

My code

```js
<ImageBackground resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={this.state.loadingImage ?
    { uri:`${this.state.filePath}` }
    :
    { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.state.filePath.data }}
    style={styles.previewImage} >
</ImageBackground>

styles

 previewImage: {
    width: 450,
    height: 350,
    alignItems: 'baseline',
  },
```

The image container is marked as a red box. Inside that red box, image should be displayed

[image]

Comment: Provide previewImage object, please.

Comment: @J.Doe Added a screenshot and the style sheet

Comment: @J.Doe And one more update is when I reload my application I could see a blink of my image after that it shows

Comment: Try to set dummy URI to source and see if it displays something.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes dummy URI worked.

Comment: So the problem is in your state. What's **this.state.filePath**? Did you log it?

Comment: Yes I tried and it returned me the image path file:///data/user/0/com.project/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20201209_230314.jpg

Comment: Remove ternary operator and leave only **uri: this.state.filePath** and check.

Comment: Same issue. This was working perfectly, last day I have migrated my app to Android 10 after this issue came into the picture.